# cPanel overrides PHP

Tags: fastcgi, php

I'm trying to run Nginx web server along side with cPanel.
I've had Nginx up and running already and the site was working perfectly, but after installing cPanel, looks like it overrided the PHP.

Current error from error.log:

> connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

This error suggests that there's a problem with FastCGI or php-fpm. When I try to restart php-fpm service, I get this error:

> Starting php-fpm: [23-Aug-2013 00:30:31] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so' - libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   [23-Aug-2013 00:30:31] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so' - libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   [23-Aug-2013 00:30:31] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so' - libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the recent changes you made have either overwritten your PHP installation OR the path to your modules `/usr/lib64/php/modules/` is not valid anymore.

I would look at the PHP Configuration by using:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then copy the configuration you see there and add the additional modules you need to the configuration and recompile PHP from source. This should resolve the issue for you.

If you cannot get PHP to run at all right now, you can still get the configuration by running this from the command line:

```
php -i | head
```

You can also temporarily disable those missing modules by editing your php.ini file. After doing so PHP should start without any problems.

**Edit 1:** You can find and change your `extension_dir` path in the php.ini file.

Comment: Where exactly do I change that? Where can I configure the modules path? Because it looks to be okay from FTP.